# How do i get MySqlWorkBench Connections into DBeaver?

Tags: mysql-workbench, dbeaver

How do i get MySqlWorkBench Connections into DBeaver?

I am using MySqlWorkbench, I have several connections. I want to export the connections and then import them into DBeaver. I tried this, but export is zip import is csv/xml

- MSW Tools->Configuration->Backup Connections, this exports as zip file.
- DBeaver File->Import->Third Party Configuration->Custom->Popular->MySql-> (CSV or XML)

I am running on a MAC

Comment: Extract the content of zip file, which contains XMLs

Comment: the zip contains 2 XMLs, none of them is recognized !